# Select n last linesChubb from table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to grab the last n inserts in a relational table without using a Date field ?

For example in the table `Author`:

```
Author(authid, f_name, l_name)
```

Also, authid is not a natural number (eg. 1,2,3,4..) but a string (example: JohnM32015)

I am using MySQL.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MySQL with engine=InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *table* doesn't have a guaranteed sort order.  A *query* does, if it explicitly defines one.  If, for example, your records have an incrementing `authid` value then the last N inserts would be the highest N values for that column.  So you'd order by that column descending and take the top N:

```
SELECT * FROM Author ORDER BY authid DESC LIMIT 10
```

However you define "the last N", you specify that definition in your query in a descending sort order and take the top N records from that result.

Comment: My problem is not having authid as a natural number but it is a string for example JohnM32015

Comment: @JoãoPedro: That's unfortunate then.  Because you can only sort by the data you have.  I recommend adding an identity column to the table, it makes a much better primary key than a user-input string does.

Comment: @JoãoPedro: Well, an auto-incrementing identity serves a very different purpose than a date.  It's not really an alternative.  A date can be very useful when wanting to capture date values and potentially sort by them.

Answer (score 1):

If the `authid` is auto-increment then you can do

```
select * from author
order by authid desc
```

To get only a limited number of records use `top n` in SQL-Server or `limit n` in MySQL for instance.

Comment: My authid is a string made by the user, for example JohnM32015

Comment: Then no, no chance of knowing the insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you want the "most recent" 10 records, you would write your query just like the other answers say, but `order by` the field(s) that defines your case for "most recent". Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY <your date field(s)> DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Disclaimer: If you don't have data in the table to define whatever should be the "most recent" records (like a "DateInserted" field, or an auto-incrementing field), then you don't really have an easy way of doing this with SQL.